# Ubuntu resolution isuue, Graphics in setting is llvmpipe(LLVM 9.0,256bit)

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution, hybrid-graphics

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm using a 18.04.4 LTS version.

Upon installation my screen resolution is fixed at 800*600. My system graphics is showing `llvmpipe(LLVM 9.0,256bit)`.

In **Software updates > additional setting > The nvidia corporation and intel corporation** are showing `unknown`.

Can anyone give a detailed step by step process on how to fix this?

I'm using a msigl63-9rcx
8Gb RAM, 300Gb for Linux, dual boot Windows 10
Have a GPU Nvidia GTX 1050 ti.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open a terminal and run this command

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@peterpang_84917/personal-experience-of-installing-ubuntu-18-04-lts-on-xps-15-9570-3e53b6cfeefe

this link provides the solution for the llvm pipe issue.

1.Open the terminal.

2.Type sudo gedit /etc/default/grub .

GRUB_DEFAULT=0

GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden

GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodset"

3.modify the last 2 commands to

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

and save.

4.sudo update-grub & rebooot.

refer link if any doubts

this solved the llvm pipe issue.
now  the system graphics is:Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2)
i'm able to adjust the resoution and brightness.

but still i'm not able to install nvidia drivers &
In Software updates > additional setting > The nvidia corporation and intel corporation are showing unknown. as well
can anyone please help... thanks in advance